# PHP memory usage for fopen in append mode

Tags: php, cakephp, memory-management, fopen

I have a custom CakePHP shopping cart application where I’m trying to create a CSV file that contains a row of data for each transaction.  I’m running into memory problems when having PHP create the CSV file at once by compiling the relevant data in the MySql databse. Currently the CSV file contains about 200 rows of data.

Alternatively, I’ve considered creating the CSV in a piecemeal process by appending a row of data to the file every time a transaction is made using: fopen($mFile.csv, 'a');

My developers are saying that I will still run into memory issues with this approach when the CSV file gets too large as PHP will read the whole file into memory.  Is this the case? When using the append mode will PHP attempt to read the whole file into memory? If so, can you recommend a better approach?

Thanks in advance,
Ben

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran the following script for a few minutes, and generated a 1.4gb file, well over my php memory limit.  I also read from the file without issue.  If you are running into memory issues it is probably something else that is causing the problem.

```
$fp = fopen("big_file.csv","a");

for($i = 0; $i < 100000000; $i++)
{
    fputcsv($fp , array("val1","val2","val3","val4","val5","val6","val7","val8","val9"));
}
```

Comment: That answers the question.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

can't you just export from the db like so:

```
SELECT list_fields INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/result.text'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
FROM test_table;
```

Comment: The data is stored in multiple tables and must be processed a bit to be in the required format which is where I think the memory issues arise. With your suggestion of exporting from the db, wouldn't there also be memory issues when the data amount gets large?

Comment: you could create a temp table, and export from there, i suspect it will have a smaller memory footprint than reading the whole thing in to memory and processing through php. 200 rows is tiny to have memory issues, i read a few million at a time for some projects

Comment: Thanks Dragon, that may be the better option than creating CSV files.